# Accessing the Stack Exchange home page from a community page

Tags: feature-request, design, top-bar, navigation

I am trying to understand how to go to the Stack Exchange homepage from a Stack Exchange community's page.

Here's where I want to go:

[image]

I like this page because it's full of questions. It's exciting.
It's also very similar to the home page for the iOS app, where the user can scroll through questions.

Let's say I am in the Graphic Design Stack Exchange community, clicking on the "StackExchange" logo on top left will open a menu rather than link me where I want to go:

[image]

Once the menu is open, clicking on Stack Exchange logo closes it.

Nothing in the menu takes me to the home page. The closest thing is this link, "More Stack Exchange Communities":

[image]

But this link takes me there:

[image]

Although the URL is close, that's not where I want to go.

Note that the footer doesn't link to Stack Exchange's home page either:

[image]

(note the strange behaviour of the right-side bar which I already mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267322/focus-changes-when-adding-tags-with-safari)).

So, is there a simple way to access the home page of Stack Exchange from any community page (and I don't mean by typing a URL or having a favorite in the browser)?

Comment: Really sorry, didn't see that you don't want to change the url. I've edited my answer.

Comment: The unfortunate part is that the Stack Exchange logo shows `stackexchange.com` on mouse-over, and if the JavaScript files haven't loaded yet, it actually *does* act as a link to `stackexchange.com`.

Answer (score 3):

1. As you have said, clicking the "More stackexchange communities" brings you to the sites list. Then you just click the Stack Exchange logo to get to the home page.
2. On the right hand side of any community, there is a bar full of "Hot network questions". It's the randomly selected questions from the Stack Exchange home site, aka hot questions list. You can also click the header to get directly to the page of your desire.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the Hot Network Questions list.  Click here:

[image: screen shot with HNQ link circled]